# Want a regular expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a regular expression to convert following string :

```
([Line Item].[Line Items].&[2268], [Line Item].[Line Items» Root].&[10141]) - 
([Line Item].[Line Items].&[12640], [Line Item].[Line Items» Root].&[5500])
```

into

```
(2268) - (12640)
```

the requirement is we may have several operators '-' and/or '+' and any special  characters (such as "»") within "[]" in the first expression

my code is like this:

```
select regexp_replace('([Line Item].[Line Items].&[2268], 
       [Line Item].[Line Items» Root].&[10141]) - ([Line Item].[Line Items].&[12640], 
       [Line Item].[Line Items» Root].&[5500])', '(\[.*?\]\.)+&','') 
  from dual;
```

but I don't get what I expected. can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(..., '\([^()]+\[(\d+)\][^()]+\)', '(\1)')
```